# Magento 2 : Label not display after add field with custom type

Tags: magento2, adminform, custom-field, fieldsets

In admin form, I created custom field type and then, add html content by custom phtml file.

But, after that label not display with custom field type.

**Custom Field Type :**

```
$fieldset->addType(
    'custom_field_labels',
    '\Vendor\Magento\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Renderer\CustomField'
);

$fieldset->addField(
    'custom_text',
    'custom_field_labels',
    [
        'name' => 'custom_text',
        'label' => __('Custom Text'),
        'title' => __('Custom Text'),
    ]
);
```

> Vendor\Magento\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Renderer\CustomField.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Magento\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Renderer;


class CustomField extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement {

    protected $_blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $_blockFactory
    ) {
        $this->_blockFactory = $_blockFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get the after element html.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getElementHtml() {
        $customDiv = $this->_blockFactory
            ->createBlock('Vendor\Magento\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Tabs\MyTab')
            ->setTemplate('Vendor_Magento::product/tabs/mytabs.phtml')->toHtml();
        return $customDiv;
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I solve that issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check __construct() in this file.

> Vendor\Magento\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Renderer\CustomField.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Magento\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Renderer;

class CustomField extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    protected $_blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $factoryElement,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
        Escaper $escaper,
        $data = [],
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $_blockFactory
    ) {
        $this->_blockFactory = $_blockFactory;
        parent::__construct($factoryElement, $factoryCollection, $escaper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get the after element html.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getElementHtml() {
        $customDiv = $this->_blockFactory
            ->createBlock('Vendor\Magento\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Tabs\MyTab')
            ->setTemplate('Vendor_Magento::product/tabs/mytabs.phtml')->toHtml();
        return $customDiv;
    }
}
```

This will work :)

Comment: Why object manager?

Comment: I've updated content for this file, please check this code that will definitely works now. :)